Associating B-Spline Coefficients to Control Points
From the seminal paper by Hughes I learnt that any B-Spline curve (or surface) can be described by a linear combination of B-Spline basis and control points, i.e.
C(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n N_{i,p} B_i

where N_{i,p} denotes the i-th node of the B-Spline curve with order p, and B_i the coefficients, or the control points.
This works well if we have a pre-defined plane, and summing up the parts give the desired B-Spline curve/surface.
My question is: is there a way to express the B-Spline curve in the same manner where it is not necessarily a function (vertical line can have multiple intersections with the curve), for example how to write the B-Spline curve in the form above for the following curve?

The curve is drawn using nurbs calculator. This is basically a curve with both vertical and horizontal components, with zigzags on both of them (there exists vertical/horizontal lines intersect with the curve at two points, respectively)
Clearly for a curve that is not necessarily a function (such as the one above) it cannot be decomposed directly into the bases. I am wondering how, then, can it be expressed explicitly using the same formulation.
Both analytic and numerical expressions will be very useful. Thanks in advance!

What's your question?

If you decompose your curve from f[x, y, z] into x[t], y[t], z[t] with t being simple linear space defined within your curve limits, and then for each t just compute the points (x, yu, z), will it be fine?

You seem not to be familiar with parametric equations. We are not in a context y=f(x), but x=f(t), y=g(t), which even allows closed curves.

The B-Spline curve you're seeking is a parametric curve C(t) = [X(t), Y(t), Z(t)], where:
X(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n N_{i,p}(t) Pi_x
Y(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n N_{i,p}(t) Pi_y
Z(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n N_{i,p}(t) Pi_z
Pi are the control points (Pi_x for example, is the x-coordinate of the i'th control point) and N_{i,p}(t) is the (scalar) i'th basis function (of degree p, which is 2 in your example).
The parameter t goes from 0 to 1 (in your example).
The basis functions can be computed directly from the knots using the Cox-DeBoor recursion formula.
So in vector form the curve can be written as: C(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n N_{i,p}(t) Pi.
A good introductory website, which explains this and more (and gives you, among other things, the Cox-De Boor formula) is this online course by Shene.
I highly recommend you read the chapter on B-Spline curves and in particular, on B-Spline basis functions.
So, if you implement the Cox-DeBoor recursion formula, you can densely sample points on the curve (e.g., by evaluating Ni(t) for t=[0,0.01,...,0.99,1]) and draw it or perform other tasks on it.
A C-like implementation for computing the B-Spline basis functions can be found in Algorithm A2.2 of The NURBs Book by Piegl and Tiller.
A note on your representation: The control points in your example have four coordinates (e.g., the first is [-6.386, 4.902, 0, 1]). The fourth coordinate is required to support rational B-Splines (NURBs), which can be thought of as an extension of B-Splines. In your context, where all the fourth coordinates are equally 1, you can ignore the fourth coordinate and consider just the first three coordinates as values of Pi_x, Pi_y, Pi_z as I explained above.

Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, and related information! I was thinking in the frame of canonical case (with a flat plane, and visualize the linear combination as aggregating the scaled basis functions) and forgot about the parametric nature of curves lol
